# How can I use the Offset patch for X seconds after the user starts recording?

Tags: spark-ar-studio

The runtime patch starts counting as soon as the effect is open which is not necessarily whilst the user is recording. How can I wait for 2 seconds after the user has started recording?

Answer (score 0):

See the patch configuration in the link below. It turns a plane visible 2 seconds after the user has started recording.

Here's how it works:

- When somebody starts recording, a 'Pulse' is sent that resets the offset timer, starting a fresh 2 second countdown.
- An 'And' patch makes sure we're only responding to 2 second countdown events when the camera is recording.

[screenshot: patch layout to delay 2 seconds after camera started recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKxAG.png)